# Alternative to .replace() replacer function needed for multiple matches in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, string-matching

I'm working on a project that does some string parsing (for a song lyrics format) and I ran across a usage of the `.replace()` method that feels a bit hacky to me... but it does work.

This is how it currently works right now, and it logs out the expected result.

```js
const scan = (str, pattern) => {
  const results = [];

  str.replace(pattern, function() {
    results.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, -2));
  });

  return _.flatten(results)
}

console.log("Lyrics", scan(
  "I don't see! a bad, moon a-rising. (a-rising)",
  /(\[[\w#b/]+])?([\w\s',.!()_\-"]*)/gi
));

console.log("Chords", scan(
  "[D] [D/F#] [C] [A7]",
  /\[([\w#b+/]+)]?/gi
));

console.log("Measures", scan(
  `
# Instrumental

| [A] [B] | [C] | [D] [E] [F] [G] |
`,
  /([[\w#b/\]+\]\s]+)[|]*/gi
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The usage of `.replace()` feels wrong since it's not actually doing any replacing but relying on the looping behavior to push items into an array.  That returns an array with a single item, of an array of strings.  Lodash is then used to flatten it out into a single string array.

I feel like this could be improved to use `.matchAll()` instead, but I haven't been able to get it quite right just yet.  Here's what I have so far, which works but the output is wrong since it's not identical to the above example.

```js
const scan = (str, pattern) => {
  return [...str.matchAll(pattern)].map(r=>{
    return r[1]
});
}

console.log("Lyrics", scan(
  "I don't see! a bad, moon a-rising. (a-rising)",
  /(\[[\w#b/]+])?([\w\s',.!()_\-"]*)/gi
));

console.log("Chords", scan(
  "[D] [D/F#] [C] [A7]",
  /\[([\w#b+/]+)]?/gi
));

console.log("Measures", scan(
  `
# Instrumental

| [A] [B] | [C] | [D] [E] [F] [G] |
`,
  /([[\w#b/\]+\]\s]+)[|]*/gi
));
```

Is `.matchAll()` the correct alternative to `.replace()` in this case? Is there a better way to get the desired output instead of what I am currently doing?  I know I'm currently not calling the `.slice()` method that the first example has yet because I'm not entirely sure I understand what this is trying to accomplish here since this code was not originally written by me.

Comment: What exactly should the regex match? Everything is optional, and `\w` also matches `b` and `_` Is there a predifined format for the lyrics?

Comment: What is the task you're trying to accomplish? "undefined, same, undefined < works fine!" fine what? Seems odd to begin with

Comment: It just seems odd to use `.replace()` as a loop to push items into an array, and just a string is returned that never gets used.

Comment: Regarding the pattern matching, in the project this function is generalized so that a string and a pattern are passed in and the results are returned.  I just chose this example for the question since the results differed in my two examples

Comment: I've edited my question to show more sample data/regexes now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` and `slice`.

```js
const pattern = /(\[[\w#b/]+])?([\w\s',.!()_\-"]*)/gi;
const str = "I don't see! a bad, moon a-rising. (a-rising)";

const results =  [...str.matchAll(pattern)].flatMap(m => m.slice(1));

console.log('results', results)
```